# Joining variables created during a loop into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, series

I've been storing variables using a for loop in Python 3.8 that goes like this

```
i = len(df.columns) 

for n in range (0,i):
    x = df.iloc[:,n]
    y = #variable with observed values
    sl, ic = stats.linregress(x,y)

    var = ((sl*x)+ic)

    globals()['var_'+str(n)] = var
    #endfor
```

the  `globals` function returns a variable (Series) stored with a number ranging from `0` to `i`, with this structure `var_number`.

I'd like to store all variables in a DataFrame... is there a way? Do I have to add the command inside the loop or after?

Comment: i would recommend creating a dictionary instead of dynamically added variables to `globals`

Comment: Is the value of the 'var' variable obtained from df ? If so, wouldn't renaming the columns of df with 'var_number' suffice ?
Need more information on the variable itself... maybe a reproducible example ?

Comment: @PaulH I'v modified a little the post so that maybe the procedure is more clear

Comment: `df` and `y` are undefined, so this still isn't clear. but my point stands. don't dynamically add things to the namespace. create a single dictionary and add each value with a meaningful key

Comment: Sorry I meant to tag @MathewPaul, who asked for more information on the code